# How do you specify a heterogeneity random effect using sparse.sglmm in package ngspatial?

Tags: r, models, spatial, poisson

I have created a spatial Poisson model using package ngspatial (Hughes). My data is aggregated to census tracts with the variables `violent`, `g5prop`, and `conc_dis`. I would like to fit a hetereogeneity random effect (i.e. random effect for each census tract). How is this accomplished?

Here is what I have for my model, and it works beautifully:

```
library(ngspatial)

Z = stl$violent
X = cbind(1, stl$g5prop, stl$conc_dis)
load("A.Rda") # adjacency matrix
set.seed(123456)
fit = sparse.sglmm(Z ~ X - 1 + offset(log(stl$total_pop)), 
    random = 1|stl$id, family=poisson, A=A, 
    attractive=40,tune=list(sigma.s = 0.02), 
    verbose = TRUE)
summary(fit)
```

Now, how do I specify a random effect? It doesn't function like `lme4` (for example `(1|subject)`) or other formulas (`random = 1~subject`).

Thanks!

Comment: what is the `random = 1|stl$id` argument in your model doing?  It doesn't seem to be listed in the arguments in the help file for `sparse.sglmm()` ...

Comment: maybe (??) specify the `hyper` argument?  Maybe look at the original reference?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I was expecting this to work like panel data or like nested (hierarchical) data - where you use the syntax like lme4 or other packages. I was able to figure out how to do this. To specify heterogeneity random effects, you simply use the hyper=(a,b) argument and specify the priors for a and b. There is no additional code to put in the actual model statement. So, it would look like this:              fit = sparse.sglmm(Z ~ X - 1 + offset(log(stl$total_pop)), 
    family=poisson, A=A, hyper=(.001,.001),
    attractive=40,tune=list(sigma.s = 0.02), 
    verbose = TRUE)

Comment: could you please post that as an answer to your question?